# Handling react route 404 with htaccess

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

I am deploying a react app to a subdirectory on an existing site. The react directory is analogous to `domain.com/react`. I want to use a rule in `/react/.htaccess` to handle 404s that result from directly navigating to routes.

For example, a user navigates to `domain.com/react/somepage/otherpage`, the page does not exist, and the `domain.com/react/index.js` file is instead able to handle the route with react router thanks to the `.htaccess` rule.

Can anyone tell me how to write the `.htaccess` rule that I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Following. I know it has been nearly a year.